# How to sort a comma-delimited string?

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have the following Ruby code:

```
settings= hash.new
settings= batch.getPartialSettings
settings= batchSettings.merge(batch.getEntireSettings)
puts settings
```

The result is:

```
{"Resolution"=>"1024", "Applications"=>"Mozilla,IE,Chrome", "Programming"=>"Java,HTML"}
```

I want `"Applications"` to be sorted as:

```
"Applications"=>"Chrome,IE,Mozilla"
```

So, my final result should be:

```
{"Resolution"=>"1024", "Applications"=>"Chrome,IE,Mozilla", "Programming"=>"Java,HTML"}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary to add salutations ("hi!"), valedictions ("thanks a lot") or signatures to questions because Stack Overflow isn't a bulletin board. It's a question and answer reference site; Think of it like a cook book or an encyclopedia. People ask questions and others supply answers on how to do it. We don't care if you're new to a language or have worked with it for years, a well-asked question is what is important.

Comment: @theTinMan You frequently seem to edit and add question marks to titles where putting one is grammatically wrong. What is that? If you edit, you should be careful not to make it wrong.

Comment: Questions end with question marks. It's acceptable to write a terse question, but, even so, they always end with question marks.

Comment: @theTinMan In this case, the title is not a question. It is a phrase.

Comment: @UliAgassi If you intended to make sense of the question mark, "How to ..." is a (nominal) phrase, is it not a question, and the question mark is still inappropriate. If you change it to "How can I ...", then it is a question, and the question mark becomes appropriate.

Comment: @UliAgassi Are you sure you mean coma? It doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsorted_apps = settings['Applications']
sorted_apps = unsorted_apps.split(',').sort.join(',')
settings['Applications'] = sorted_apps
```